# Grouped UITableView custom draw cell, without changing background color?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am custom drawing a table cell in a grouped cell. How do I get the background color right?

I actually have a view inside the cell, and am customizing how that view is drawn in its `drawRect:`.
I tried this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    BOOL isHighlighted = self.highlighted;
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if ( !isHighlighted ) {
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect( c, frame );
    }

    // rest of drawing
}
```

This works well with the plain table view, but it isn't a match for the grouped table view. It looks like about a 96% grey.

It looks like this:

[image: White box]

If your screen isn't calibrated well, you might not see the difference. But it's there.

When I tried this:

```
    if ( !isHighlighted ) {
        //[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
        //CGContextFillRect( c, frame );
    }
```

I instead got a black background, like this:

[image: Black box]

My assumption is that I need to fill every pixel in my draw routine.

When I try this:

```
    if ( !isHighlighted ) {
        [[self backgroundColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect( c, frame );
    }
```

I also get the black background. I think the `backgroundColor` of my view is `transparentColor`.

I've tried this, too:

```
    if ( !isHighlighted ) {
        CGContextFillRect( c, frame );
    }
```

Same black box.

How do I match the background color of a grouped table view, without using the eyedropper and hard-coding a `[UIColor colorWithWhite: alpha:]` into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the background colour of its super view

```
UIColor * background = [self.superview backgroundColor];
```

I think calling `[super drawRect:rect];` at the top of your custom draw rect will fix this problem

Comment: I had to go two superviews out, but this approach worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
 [[UIColor clearColor] set];
```